# Use of CODE tag in HTML, How to I get it to display the code?

Tags: javascript, html

Quick question,
If I want to document some code on a basic HTML and put that within a CODE tag, how can I quickly convert the code between those tags when the page renders to display properly? I know I can write a javascript find and replace and search through the string over and over until its done replacing all the characters, but is there a better way?

Or, is there a jQuery way to do it if I need to use javascript?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say 'display properly'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you may be looking for syntax highlighting.  Take a look at [google's syntax highlihter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)

Answer (score 7):

I think the `<code>` tag is more for displaying with a certain font, rather than layout. `<code>` seems to just use a monospaced font.

You might be looking for the `<pre>` tag (for pre formatted). That will preserve line breaks and spaces.

Unless the code you are trying to display is HTML code itself, then I think you'd have to change all the `<`'s to `&lt;`'s ahead of time

Comment: Let's not forget about changing & to &amp;! And while you're replacing <'s, you should also replace >'s for consistency (even if >'s will be ignored by the browser).

Comment: Actually, ampersands display correctly by them selves as long as they don't end up matching and existing html entity code. You are right that they probably should be "escaped". Replacing the >'s is just a matter of preference, I personally prefer to see the > to remind me that there's a tag there.